# how to prove homomorphism with identity element

Tags: group-homomorphism

I have this,
Let $\phi: G → G$ defined by $\phi(x) = e$ , for all $x\in G$ ,where $e$ is the identity element. How to show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: Try to solve it using intuition. A homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ between groups $G$ and $H$ means that when we multiply two elements in $G$  and map it to $H$ it is the same as to multiply the two mappings of the individual elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to see that $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$ for all $x,y \in G$. But $\phi(xy) = e = e\cdot e = \phi(x)\phi(y)$. So $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

These kinds of early group theory proofs about the identity pretty much always rely on the fact that $e\cdot e = e$. Another similar problem is to prove that the identity is unique -- i.e., if there are two elements $e$ and $f$ in $G$ with $ex = xe = x$ and $fx = xf = x$ for all $x \in G$, then $e=f$. See if you can work that one out too.

Comment: Thanks. Its a simple logic that involved.